# How do I solve the problem: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i am basically trying to make a book marker application using vanilla JS which stores the websites entered as a bookmark and can delete the bookmark when the delete icon is pressed. I am trying to return the site url value to the delete function using the onclick() in HTML. However, I am getting the following error when I click the delete icon

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

I am not sure what the problem is.

BMtoDisp is the array that hold the JSON object which contains the websites stored. 
siteName contains the name of the site from the JSON file
siteURL contains the site URL from the JSON file
dBM is a div that displays the bookmarks after being stored.
delBM() is the function to which i want to return the siteURL and does the delete action when the Trash Can (fontawesome) icon is clicked.

```
for(var i = 0; i < BMtoDisp.length; i++)
{
    var siteName = BMtoDisp[i].sname;
    var siteURL = BMtoDisp[i].surl;
    dBM.innerHTML +="<div id='newElement'>" + '<h2>' + siteName + '</h2>' + '<a target="_blank" href=" '+siteURL+'">' + siteURL + '</a>' + '<a onclick="delBM('+siteURL+')"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i><a/>';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding single quotes to wrap the value you want to pass in the function call? `onclick="delBM(\''+siteURL+'\')"`

Comment: show the `delBM()` code

Comment: you can press F12 and see line of error in console tab

Comment: try putting `console.log(siteURL)` on the line after you define it. If this string has a `(` but no `)` in it, then it'll cause this error. [What you are doing is bad style anyway, firstly `onclick` attributes in HTML are strongly discouraged for a number of good reasons, and it's also a pet peeve of mine when people use string concatenation to construct HTML strings. I've been there and done it, but as you are discovering, it's incredibly brittle and hard to read - try using `document.createElement` and the `appendChild` method to construct your HTML in a more maintainable way.]

Comment: @NewToJS Yes that worked perfectly fine. Could I know what that does and why did that work in my case?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I got it working using onclick="delBM(\''+siteURL+'\')".

Comment: @HienNguyen I tried doing so and i the error that came on the console tab was the one I mentioned above. I couldn't see any changes on the elements part of the inspection tool. Also i got it fixed using the method that NewToJS mentioned,

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes I did use console.log in the function I created using and it didn't execute the console.log because of the error I was getting, However I fixed it now after the method NewToJS mentioned above,

Comment: @MSM yes, I agree that this is the solution and apologise for not realising you were missing quotes. This is actually a good illustration of what I said, that building HTML content as a string is a bad way to go about things.

Comment: Post the full code..

Answer (score 1):

i have found 2 issues in the shared code snippet:

1. as @NewToJS mentioned - adding single quotes to wrap the value you want to pass in the function call
2. div ending tag is missing

**Code Snippet:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
function delBM(url){
 console.log(url);
}

var BMtoDisp = [];
BMtoDisp.push({sname: 'Ayon', surl: 'https://google.com'});
BMtoDisp.push({sname: 'Alfaz', surl: 'https://yahoo.com'});

var dBM = document.getElementById("id01");

for(var i = 0; i < BMtoDisp.length; i++)
{
    var siteName = BMtoDisp[i].sname;
    var siteURL = BMtoDisp[i].surl;
    dBM.innerHTML +='<div id="newElement'+ i +'"><h2>' + siteName + '</h2><a target="_blank" href="'+siteURL+'">' + siteURL + '</a><a onclick="delBM(\''+siteURL+'\')">delete me<a/></div>';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh yes i did not notice that the ending <div> tag was missing. I must have erased it by mistake while modifying the code and did not realize it. Thank you for pointing that out. The code is working perfectly fine and the function is deleting the bookmark as well.